# How to use custome template in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I want to use my own template in Joomla 1.5.
But I don't know how I can do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way i think is to the templates subdirectory in Joomla!, duplicate one of the existing template subdirectories and give it a name my_template and then modify that. In the Joomla! admin you can select the new template and it will be applied.

If it all goes horribly wrong you can simply delete the directory and you will not have done any damage to the rest of the site.

One the Joomla! site there are a number of tutorials on how to do it you can work along with

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from here
http://www.phpeveryday.com/pack/Joomla-Template-Step-By-Step-Tutorial